# MULE ESB - simple jaxws client don't work ... - Message payload is of type: ContentLengthInputStream

Tags: java, web-services, mule, esb, mule-studio

Hi guys first of all I want you to see my wsdl file it's DHL24 api I want learn a bit on this and use simple example here is the link https://dhl24.com.pl/webapi.html

I want to use **getVersion** as you can see we don't need to provide any data to this only in response we have **getVersionResult** - STRING

First of all I created package generated from apache CTX using simple project here is POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>pl.test</groupId>
<artifactId>DhlServiceClient</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <apache.cxf-version>2.5.9</apache.cxf-version>
</properties>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${apache.cxf-version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>Wsdl2Java - gasShopService.wsdl</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                        <sourceRoot>${basedir}/src/main/java/</sourceRoot>
                        <wsdlOptions>
                            <wsdlOption>
                                <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/dhlService.wsdl</wsdl>
                                <extraargs>
                                    <extraarg>-client</extraarg>
                                    <extraarg>-autoNameResolution</extraarg>
                                    <extraarg>-p</extraarg>
                                    <extraarg>pl.test</extraarg>
                                    <extraarg>-aer=false</extraarg>
                                    <extraarg>-verbose</extraarg>
                                    <extraarg>-frontend</extraarg>
                                    <extraarg>jaxws21</extraarg>
                                    <extraarg>-wsdlLocation </extraarg>
                                    <extraarg>classpath:dhlService.wsdl</extraarg>
                                </extraargs>
                            </wsdlOption>
                        </wsdlOptions>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

All is fine here I have package and classes so I start to create second project (as dependency I added this package - this works fine)

Now I want to create simple flow:

```
<flow name="getVersion" doc:name="getVersion">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8088" path="getVersion" doc:name="HTTP"/>

<logger doc:name="getVersion" message="Test Before" level="ERROR"/>
<cxf:jaxws-client operation="getVersion" clientClass="pl.test.integration.dhl.ws.client.DHL24WebapiService" port="DHL24WebapiPort" enableMuleSoapHeaders="true" doc:name="SOAP">
</cxf:jaxws-client>

<logger doc:name="getVersion" message="Test after" level="ERROR"/>
</flow>
```

Nothing big but when I post to this I have:

> ERROR 2014-06-28 20:36:10,289
>   [[gaspoldhlservice].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02]
>   org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Test Before ERROR
>   2014-06-28 20:36:10,291
>   [[gaspoldhlservice].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02]
>   org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
>   ******************************************************************************** Message               : wrong number of arguments. Failed to route
>   event via endpoint: org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.
>   Message payload is of type: ContentLengthInputStream Code
>   : MULE_ERROR--2
>   -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Exception stack is:
>   1. wrong number of arguments (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException)   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl:-2 (null)
>   2. wrong number of arguments. Failed to route event via endpoint: org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor. Message payload is of
>   type: ContentLengthInputStream
>   (org.mule.api.transport.DispatchException)
>   org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor:150
>   -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Root Exception stack trace: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong
>   number of arguments   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
>
> ---

I was searching a bit in google and found something like this. I add after inbound:

```
<object-to-byte-array-transformer />
```

And I had other error:

> ERROR 2014-06-28 20:45:18,149
>   [[gaspoldhlservice].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02]
>   org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Test Before ERROR
>   2014-06-28 20:45:18,151
>   [[gaspoldhlservice].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02]
>   org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
>   ******************************************************************************** Message               : wrong number of arguments. Failed to route
>   event via endpoint: org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.
>   Message payload is of type: byte[] Code                  :
>   MULE_ERROR--2
>   -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Exception stack is:
>   1. wrong number of arguments (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException)   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl:-2 (null)
>   2. wrong number of arguments. Failed to route event via endpoint: org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor. Message payload is of
>   type: byte[] (org.mule.api.transport.DispatchException)
>   org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor:150
>   -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Root Exception stack trace: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong
>   number of arguments   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
>
> ---

I need a little bit push here its very simple method and I cant handle it right ...

**AFTER EDIT:**

Changed to your flow with:

```
<flow name="getVersion" doc:name="getVersion">
   <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8088" path="getVersion" doc:name="HTTP"/>


<cxf:jaxws-client operation="getVersion" serviceClass="pl.test.integration.dhl.ws.client.DHL24WebapiService" port="DHL24WebapiPort" enableMuleSoapHeaders="true" doc:name="SOAP">
</cxf:jaxws-client>

<http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"  address="http://localhost:8088/consumeTest" doc:name="HTTP" method="POST"/>

</flow>

<flow name="consumeTest" doc:name="consumeTest">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8088" path="consumeTest" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <logger doc:name="getVersion" message="Test AFTER" level="ERROR"/>
</flow>
```

Answer is

> No such operation: getVersion. Failed to route event via endpoint:
>   org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor. Message payload is of
>   type: ContentLengthInputStream

When I use clientClass instead of serviceClass:

> wrong number of arguments. Failed to route event via endpoint:
>   org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor. Message payload is of
>   type: ContentLengthInputStream

Answer (score 0):

You need to put an outbound endpoint after `cxf:jaxws-client` like 
 `<http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"  address="Your external webservice path that you are tying to consume " doc:name="HTTP" method="POST"/>` to post the value to the external webservice  .. 
for example If your external webservice is at `http://localhost:8086/mainData?wsdl` then you need to put

`<http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"  address="http://localhost:8086/mainData" doc:name="HTTP" method="POST"/>`  ................ and one more  thing ... could you plase change 
`<cxf:jaxws-client operation="getVersion" clientClass="pl.execon.integration.dhl.ws.client.DHL24WebapiService" port="DHL24WebapiPort" enableMuleSoapHeaders="true" doc:name="SOAP">` to

```
`<cxf:jaxws-client operation="getVersion" serviceClass="pl.execon.integration.dhl.ws.client.DHL24WebapiService" port="DHL24WebapiPort" enableMuleSoapHeaders="true" doc:name="SOAP">`  in your flow and try ...
```

So the **final flow** would be something like :-

```
 <flow name="getVersion" doc:name="getVersion">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8088" path="getVersion" doc:name="HTTP"/>


    <cxf:jaxws-client operation="getVersion" serviceClass="pl.execon.integration.dhl.ws.client.DHL24WebapiService" port="DHL24WebapiPort" enableMuleSoapHeaders="true" doc:name="SOAP">
    </cxf:jaxws-client>

    <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"  address="Your external webservice path that you are tying to consume " doc:name="HTTP" method="POST"/>
    </flow>
```

Comment: Still not working after changing to your flow looking like in comment

Comment: The edit is wrong The http:outbound-endpoint in the getVersion flow should have address pointing to the external webservice that you like to consume ... for example ..if there is a external webservice already available at http://localhost:8088/consumeTest and that you like to consume, then the flow will be working fine .. else if there is no such external webservice available then you need to expose a external service in another flow and then use that address in your http:outbound-endpoint of getVersion flow...Here the flow consumeTest should act as external webservice that you like to consume

Comment: Here example to build a external webservice :-http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Building+Web+Services+with+CXF  ...  you need to create another flow like you have created consumeTest and expose that webservice in that flow ...

Comment: To create a external webservice ..Create a another flow like :- <flow name="ExtenalService">
  <http:inbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:8088/consumeTest" exchange-pattern="request-response"> <!--Your interface class -->
  <cxf:jaxws-service serviceClass="org.example.HelloWorld"/> 
    </http:inbound-endpoint> <!--Your serviceimplemantation class class -->
    <component class="org.example.HelloWorldImpl" /> 
  </flow>  .............

Comment: Now this is an example to create the webservice you like to consume .. If you already have the webservice you don't need to create this .. rather just point the webservice path in the outbound endpoint address in your getversion flow ... for example if your external webservice wsdl is at http://localhost:8086/webapi?wsdl the just put  http://localhost:8086/webapi in http:outbound-endpoint address

Comment: To sum up I have WSDL here https://dhl24.com.pl/webapi/ So I created: <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"  address="http://dhl24.com.pl/webapi/" doc:name="HTTP" method="POST"/> Don't work still "No such operation: getVersion." If I want to change this to HTTPS I have error

Comment: Your configuration is correct now .. but my question is where is your webservice (That you want to consume ) running ?? is it running at https://dhl24.com.pl/webapi/ ? I don't think it is running there .. it's only the wsdl file uploaded there .. I cant use it to import it in SOAPUI .. If it is a java webservice then it would have url something like https://dhl24.com.pl/webapi?wsdl and could be imported to SOAPUI to test the service ... make sure where your external service is running

Comment: For example just check this external webservice .. It is a webservice created using dot net and you can test the service by importing this url in SOAPUI :- http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx?WSDL .... It has a operation getQuote and webervice is running at the url given

Comment: Without problem I import dhl24.com.pl/webapi?wsdl to soap ui and make simple request on getVersion all work my <https:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"  address="https://dhl24.com.pl/webapi?wsdl" doc:name="HTTP" method="POST"/> still giving me No such operation: getVersion.

Comment: From here I am not able to load it into SOAPUI ... anyways you need to remove ?wsdl in the address of your https:outbound-endpoint .. you can try other external service like http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?WSDL .. it has a operation called ConversionRate .. try it with your Mule flow

Comment: Check this for your reference :- http://training.middlewareschool.com/mule/consuming-wsdl-first-service/

Answer (score 0):

**AFTER EDIT:**

Changed to your flow with:

```
<flow name="getVersion" doc:name="getVersion">
   <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8088" path="getVersion" doc:name="HTTP"/>


<cxf:jaxws-client operation="getVersion" serviceClass="pl.test.integration.dhl.ws.client.DHL24WebapiService" port="DHL24WebapiPort" enableMuleSoapHeaders="true" doc:name="SOAP">
</cxf:jaxws-client>

<http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"  address="http://localhost:8088/consumeTest" doc:name="HTTP" method="POST"/>

</flow>

<flow name="consumeTest" doc:name="consumeTest">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8088" path="consumeTest" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <logger doc:name="getVersion" message="Test AFTER" level="ERROR"/>
</flow>
```

Answer is

> No such operation: getVersion. Failed to route event via endpoint:
>   org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor. Message payload is of
>   type: ContentLengthInputStream

When I use clientClass instead of serviceClass:

> wrong number of arguments. Failed to route event via endpoint:
>   org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor. Message payload is of
>   type: ContentLengthInputStream