# MULE ESB - Unexpected wrapper element

Tags: java, mule, esb

Hi guys first of all I want you to see my wsdl file it's DHL24 api I want learn a bit on this and use simple example here is the link https://dhl24.com.pl/webapi.html

I want to use **getVersion** as you can see we don't need to provide any data to this only in response we have **getVersionResult** - STRING

I have such flow:

```
<flow name="getVersion" doc:name="getVersion">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8088" path="getVersion" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <object-to-byte-array-transformer />
    <logger doc:name="getVersion" message="Test Before" level="ERROR"/>

    <expression-component doc:name="Args2SOAP">
      <![CDATA[

        payload = {  };
      ]]>
    </expression-component>

    <cxf:jaxws-client operation="getVersion" clientClass="pl.test.integration.dhl.ws.client.DHL24WebapiService" port="DHL24WebapiPort" enableMuleSoapHeaders="true" doc:name="SOAP">
    </cxf:jaxws-client>

    <logger doc:name="getVersion" message="Test after" level="ERROR"/>

</flow>
```

Here is full log from this:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16887656/fulllog.txt

I'm pretty close but still can't find the answer

Answer (score 0):

The flow doesn't have a httpoutbound endpoint to post the data to the external webservice it is consuming  .. Next step is to change **clientClass** to **serviceClass** in

```
<cxf:jaxws-client operation="getVersion" clientClass="pl.test.integration.dhl.ws.client.DHL24WebapiService" port="DHL24WebapiPort" enableMuleSoapHeaders="true" doc:name="SOAP">
    </cxf:jaxws-client>
```

Already mentioned here [MULE ESB - simple jaxws client don't work ... - Message payload is of type: ContentLengthInputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24469891/mule-esb-simple-jaxws-client-dont-work-message-payload-is-of-type-cont)